# JavaScript - How can I stop a running audio?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

How to stop this loop audio later when needed? (it keeps playing forever tested in Google Chrome Stable, Canary)

```
var song = null;
function a() {
  song = new Audio("audio/ring.wav");
  song.controls = false;
  song.loop = true;
  song.autoplay = true;
  document.body.appendChild(song);
}  

a();
```

Comment: Have you tried `song.pause();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var song = null;

function a() {
  song = new Audio("audio/ring.wav");
  song.controls = false;
  song.loop = true;
  song.autoplay = true;
  document.body.appendChild(song);
}  

a();

// Pause the audio, please note there is no stop event
song.pause();
```